# How to replace the Hibernate Callback in hibernate 4 in Spring ORM

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x, spring-orm

I used HibernateCallbacks primarily in situations where I would create threads inside service methods and had to be able to initialize lazy methods on Hibernate managed POJOs. The HibernateCallback would provide me with that session.

With Hibernate 4, the HibernateTemplate is nor longer supported Spring ORM, neither is the HibernateCallback etc
I've been trying to find a not-too-painful migration path without luck so far.

How do you replace the Hibernate Callback?

Any ideas are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Also looking for this exact answer - did you ever find any easy upgrade path?